# SSRS 2005 pass specific row from DataSet as Parameter?

Tags: sql, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a DataSet that looks like this

```
Food    Category
------  ---------
Apples  Fruit
Peas    Vegetable
Cake    Dessert
```

What I want to be able to do is pass Category as a parameter via row.  I know how to pass Parameters just not sure how to get row value X.  The reason for this is because I need to make a letter headers which addressees on the opposite side of the page and can go from 1 - 6 people.

In this example how would I pass Vegetable as the parameter?

results are dynamic and can vary from 1-6 rows, and the problem is I have to place the results strategically on the report, so I need to say some how row 2 Category value and pass to a sub report.

I have no clue whats not clear here but let me try this, I want to pass row 2 in this example and in this example it's Peas|Vegetable all this is is a sample from a DataSet.

Thanks!

Comment: You're sending letters to vegetables? Seriously, it's better to keep analogies/examples consistent, as I have no idea what you are trying to do in this scenario.

Comment: You want to pass values from each row to a sub report?

Comment: No i want to pass a specific row, like row 2 from a 6 row set

Comment: @MarkBannister no the Food|Category is the results from a SQL query, thats why i said it's the DataSet so I want to pass row 2 in this example

Comment: @MarkBannister "so I need to say some how row 2 Category value and pass to a sub report" who cares if it's a football to a car?  My whole question is how to pass a specific row from a dynamic dataset

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want to add a subreport to your main report - you can find details of how to do so [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28SQL.90%29.aspx).